# Symfony 2.8 Web Debug Toolbar Locks up Chrome

Tags: symfony, google-chrome, symfony-2.8

This just started happening and I cannot figure out why. This works fine in firefox, but when using using the debug toolbar in symfony 2.8, it completely locks up chrome. I have to go all the way into my task manager and end the process to get Chrome to close.

[image]

Here's a screenshot after waiting 30 minutes. This does not happen in Firefox at all. I've updated Chrome, Symfony, Composer, and every 3rd party library in the application.

I've never seen this before, I'm not even sure where to start troubleshooting this. Any suggestions?

To add, there's no errors being thrown in the server error logs at all. It doesn't appear to be an actual hang on the website, this is additionally confirmed by the toolbar still working in other browsers.

Comment: I already had this problem in the past. It was a bad configuration vHost, in my memories. Can you tell me what development environment do you work on? Wamp, Xamp? Thank you

Comment: Can you copy that request as curl and do it on terminal and see how it responds?

Comment: @ Le Menach - This is on a linux testing server, running CentOS7, Cpanel, php 7.X, running via Apache MPM-ITK. I've used this configuration on other servers many times and so far this is the only time I've ever seen this.

Comment: Seems like your Chrome sends xdebug-session header but Firefox does not. And your server responds to Chrome with all xdebug-specific operations but for Firefox — just send what you want.